# dhcpd not handling client hostnames properly on router machine

Tags: networking, dhcp, router, pppoe

I'm using 16.04 Xenial as the OS for my router which I just set up to connect to my broadband with ppp

I also set up dhcpd and it seems to be doing OK apart from one thing - I can't use the hostnames to identify my DHCP clients from the router, and on the clients, they can't refer to the server by hostname either.

I've got the following line in my server's `dhcpd.conf` file:

```
ddns-update-style standard;
```

although I'm not quite sure that that is any help. The following is the issue:

```
adam@lorien ~ $ ssh gondor
ssh: Could not resolve hostname gondor: Name or service not known
adam@lorien ~ $ ssh 192.168.0.3
Welcome to Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-109-generic x86_64)
```

And on the server:

```
adam@gondor:~$ ping lorien
ping: unknown host lorien
adam@gondor:~$ grep 192.168.0.219 /var/log/syslog | tail
Jan 21 17:01:38 gondor dhcpd[1277]: DHCPREQUEST for 192.168.0.219 from 18:3d:a2:be:df:2f (lorien) via enx283737034225
Jan 21 17:01:38 gondor dhcpd[1277]: DHCPACK on 192.168.0.219 to 18:3d:a2:be:df:2f (lorien) via enx283737034225
```

and I have the necessary config in the clients' `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf`:

```
send host-name = gethostname();
```

So what have I forgotten to do? I need the clients' names for the backups.

Answer (score 0):

bind9 and dhcpd need to configured so that dhcpd can put entries into bind9's records.

[Debian wiki DDNS docs](https://wiki.debian.org/DDNS)